# Rate-limited geographic data lookup

Tags: python, error-handling, geospatial

I'm looking for a code review of this python I wrote - this code reads the zipcode column value from a CSV file and calls an API to retrieve lat, long, state and city info.

It works fine and gives me the correct results, but I'm looking for ways to improve the code/my approach and exception handling. I am pretty sure there are better ways to write this long code.

All comments and suggestions as brutal as may be are mostly appreciated.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from ratelimiter import RateLimiter
API_KEY = "some_key"
zip_code_col_name = "zipcode"
RETURN_FULL_RESULTS = False
excel_data = pd.read_csv("Downloads/test_order.csv", encoding='utf8')
if zip_code_col_name not in excel_data.columns:
    raise ValueError("Missing zipcode column")
# This will put all zipcodes from column to list including duplicates , hence avoiding it.
#zipcodes = excel_data[zip_code_col_name].tolist() 
zipcodes =[]
for i in excel_data.zipcode:
    if i not in zipcodes:
        zipcodes.append(i)

def get_geo_info(zipcode, API_KEY, return_full_response=False):

    init_url = "some_url" 
    if API_KEY is not None:
        url = init_url+API_KEY+"/info.json/"+format(zipcode)+"/degrees"

    # Ping site for the reuslts:
    r= requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        #this will print error code to but in reuslt set it will be empty
        print("error is" + str(r.status_code))
    data = r.json()
    output = {
            "zipcode" : data.get('zip_code'),
        "lat" : data.get('lat'),
         "lng" : data.get('lng'),
        "city" : data.get('city'),
        "state" : data.get('state')

            }

    return output

def limited(until):
    duration = int(round(until - time.time()))
    print('Rate limited, sleeping for {:d} seconds'.format(duration))

results = []

### Putting max call to 49 for 1 hour, we can paramterized it also
rate_limiter = RateLimiter(max_calls=49, period=3600, callback=limited)

for zipcode in zipcodes:
    with rate_limiter:
        geocode_result = get_geo_info(zipcode, API_KEY, return_full_response=RETURN_FULL_RESULTS)
        results.append(geocode_result)
#print(results)
ddf = pd.DataFrame(results)
### This is to put the geo_info into same file however I would prefer it to write it to antoher file load it int staging table. to keep it for future refrence purposes.
""""df = pd.read_csv("Downloads/test_order.csv")
df['state'] = ddf.state
df['city'] = ddf.city
df['lattitude'] = ddf.lat
df['Longitude'] = ddf.lng
df['api_zip'] = ddf.zipcode
df.to_csv('Downloads/test_order.csv',index = False)"""
### This is to create a new file with the results
ddf.to_csv('Downloads/geo_info.csv',index = False)
```

Comment: Also, is `ratelimiter` the package available on PyPI (https://pypi.org/project/ratelimiter/), or something else?

Comment: @Graipher : hey, thanks ! :-) yes, while pasting it here it got off, i will correct it from next time. this works fine so was okay. :-). So while reviewing, do you take the code an run it also? Will surly take care of it. and yes, the package is same as you said.

Comment: Being able to run the code usually improves the reviews (since you notice if you break something). But you don't need to include the API code (and probably shouldn't, since people could impersonate you then), reviewers can get by without it as well. On the other hand, the code actually working (on your setup) is of course a requirement here. Note that you can (and should in this case) [edit] your question. The only thing not allowed is modifying the code itself after having received answers (for that you would have to ask a new question).

Comment: Thanks again @Graipher That helps a lot . I am gonna take care of all the points always, let me start with correcting the indentation first.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the zipcode data imported from the CSV file. This should probably be contained in its own method:

```
def get_zipcodes(zip_code_col_name, file_name="Downloads/test_order.csv"):
    excel_data = pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding='utf8')
    if zip_code_col_name not in excel_data.columns:
        raise ValueError("Missing zipcode column")
    return excel_data[zip_code_col_name].unique().tolist()
```

Note that `pandas.Series` objects have a [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) method that avoids your expensive loop (the `in` lookup is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ for lists). If that was not the case you could have used `set(excel_data[zip_code_col_name].tolist())`, instead. The `tolist` is not strictly needed, since a `pandas.Series` is also iterable (and that is all you do with it).

Your main code should also be in a function (called `main`, if you can think of nothing else):

```
def main():
    # Putting max call to 49 for 1 hour
    get_geo_info_limited = RateLimiter(max_calls=49, period=3600, callback=limited)(get_geo_info)

    results = [get_geo_info_limited(zipcode, API_KEY, RETURN_FULL_RESULTS) for zipcode in zipcodes]
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.to_csv('Downloads/geo_info.csv', index=False)
```

Here I used the fact that `RateLimiter` can also be used as a decorator (which is usually done using the `@RateLimiter` syntax during function definition, but can also be done manually like here) and a list comprehension instead of a manual `for` loop.

You can then call this `main` function under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to enable importing from this module from another script.

Comment: could you please help me with this line please?- results = [get_geo_info_limited(zipcode, API_KEY, RETURN_FULL_RESULTS) for zipcode in zipcodes], how do i put the results of get_zipcodes function in there?

Comment: Never mind , got it :-)

Comment: Could we do something about api_key also? it should not be hard coded , right?

Comment: @BlackCurrant: You already did something about it. It is already a parameter of the `get_geo_info` function, so you can just load a value from some config file (or the environment, or...) in the `main` method, instead of using the global constant, and pass that on.

Comment: @BlackCurrant You could pass it as an argument to the script. There are multiple methods to do that. For example, using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) as demonstrated [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/134010/52915).

Comment: @Mast: perfect thanks, I will read it in detail. and also thanks for your inputs on changing the code too.

Comment: @Graipher : I am not sure if its the right way to ask fro help for another questions but i have another one which needs review and nobody is looking at it. Would you be able to please have a look and suggest something ? Point me to right direction pls.                                                                                  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209099/simple-python-script-using-ecbxrate-to-get-historical-exchange-rate-between-curr

Comment: @BlackCurrant Sure, what's the link, I can have a look later.

Comment: thanks a lot here it is- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209099/simple-python-script-using-ecbxrate-to-get-historical-exchange-rate-between-curr